# Make different loss functions for different features in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a model that has 5 input features, the input looks like this:

```
- 500.0  --  499.752  --  499.813  --  0.061  --  -0.016 -
- 499.91  --  499.763  --  499.828  --  0.064  --  0.005 -
- 499.83  --  499.768  --  499.828  --  0.06  --  0.021 -
- 499.91  --  499.779  --  499.841  --  0.062  --  0.035 -
- 499.95  --  499.792  --  499.858  --  0.066  --  0.045 -
- 500.0  --  499.807  --  499.879  --  0.073  --  0.054 -
- 500.0  --  499.821  --  499.898  --  0.077  --  0.06 -
- 500.0  --  499.834  --  499.914  --  0.079  --  0.065 -
- 500.0  --  499.847  --  499.927  --  0.08  --  0.069 -
- 499.96  --  499.855  --  499.932  --  0.077  --  0.071 -
- 500.0  --  499.866  --  499.943  --  0.077  --  0.072 -
- 500.0  --  499.876  --  499.951  --  0.076  --  0.074 -
- 500.0  --  499.885  --  499.959  --  0.074  --  0.075 -
- 500.0  --  499.894  --  499.965  --  0.072  --  0.076 -
- 499.99  --  499.901  --  499.969  --  0.068  --  0.075 -
```

As you see, Features 1,2 and 3 move around 500, and features 4 and 5 move around zero.
I have a single MSE loss function, which is making the model predict a similar number across all features.

An example:

```
Should have predicted:
- 500.0  --  499.866  --  499.943  --  0.077  --  0.072 -

But predicted:
- 34.875  --  22.658  --  42.792  --  -4.824  --  -24.389 -
```

You can see how it tries to produce numbers that all similar.
You can also see this in training when the model will get more accurate but have higher losses.

What I am looking for is a way to make a separate MSE loss for features 1, 2, and 3, and then another for 4 and 5, so the model can actually output in a feature specific range.

I also thought about scaling features 4 and 5 up to the same range as 1, 2, and 3, but I don't know if that will work as well.

If there are any other possible solutions please share.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall add to @Meysam's answer that MinMaxScaller in scikit learn have an `inverse_transform` function which allows to reproduce the initial values.

For example, you may have :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(Y)

(... training here ...)

Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Your predicted model will be scaled obviously, so if you want to get the values at the initial scaling, you should use the same scaler:

```
Y_pred_original_scaling = scaler.inverse_transform(Y_pred)
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the problem above, are you sure your model implementation is correct?
However, for your case I think it is good to use `Min-Max scaler` which scale the values of all features between 0 and 1 (by default) and then apply model and compare results.